# JS world map plugin with custom regions

Tags: javascript, jquery, world-map

I try to display a big world map on my website with Javascript and/or Jquery.
The particularity is that I have to set and draw specific region with a custom list of countries. Exemple :

- All the countries with French language (France, Belgium, Switzerland etc...)
- All the countries with Spanish language (Spain, Columbia etc...)

Then, the visitors would be able to click on these custom areas to get more info. I found a lot of plugins (Google GeoChart, Mapael, Kartograph, jVectorMap) but no one seems to serve my purpose.

I'd like to avoid HTML image map.
Thanks !

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ may this helps you!

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems like you're looking for a plugin or library recommendation, which is off-topic for SO. Also note it's highly unlikely that anything like this exists off the shelf, and if it did it's even less likely to be free. You will most likely need to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Question is pretty broad but I will try my best:

Your best bet is to use the JavaScript API and embed a map in a div, from there you will have access to Google Maps API.

In terms of your implementation, I guess you could go a couple different ways, you could show 2 different markers for Spanish and French countries with click listeners and more info on the country, or you could get more fancy and draw polygons/polylines. If you go Marker route, it's easier so I would recommend that.